# Bootstrap: Two elements in one line?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with my verified icon.
So what I actually want is that the verified Icon like on Twitter or Facebook is besides the Username and not in the next line under my username.
But it does not work.

```
<ul class="line">
     <li>
        <h3 align="center">Username</h3>
        <span class="label label-info">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </span>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
li.line {
    list-style: none;
}

ul.line {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
h3 is a block element
```

change it to inline element

```
<ul class="line">
  <li>
     <span align="center">Username</span>
     <span class="label label-info">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
     </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It worked but now the text-size is smaller than before and the list point is there. I just want to find a way how I can place it together in one line. Is an list the wrong way?

Comment: you can change the text size by using <span style="font-size:20px">Username</span>. List is fine, it depends on what looks you're after. You can use <h3>Username <span class="label label-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span></span></h3> also.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the list point, then I don't think `li` is what you'll want to use. A `span` or even a `div` could probably give you the look you're going for.

As for having them on the same line, try using the [inline-block](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp) option for your css display element.  It is similar to `display: block`, but it allows you to keep your elements on the same line.

Comment: But this method only works when I am using <span> and not <h3> ... Do you know a trick how I can use <h3> without going in a new line?

Comment: Check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3XsJF/30/).  Uses an `h3` and a `span` together on the same line.  You would just have to change it to use the right glyphicon